# 301 Redirect Dynamic URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dynamic-url

OK so I have the following as part of the URL: /user/26872-essi/
and I'm going to final URL of /essi/

I currently have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user\/([0-9]+)\-.+[/]?$ /user.php?user_id=$1
```

So I tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user\/([0-9]+)\-.+[/]?$ /$2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(((?!\.|\/).){1,})\/?$ /user.php?username=$1
```

It doesn't seem to be passing the variable in. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: If you have URL as `/essi/` in browser then how will `user.php` get the number e.g. `26872` ?

Comment: OK, so /user/user_id-username/ is the basic pattern of existing url. In PHP I changed the site to accept just /username/ - that part works. So essentially I want /user/user_id-username/ to go to /username/ so the last rewrite rule kicks in (user.php?username=$1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/\d+-([\w-]+)/?$ /$1/ [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ user.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yes that did it! Thank you anubhava. Question, can you explain what I was doing wrong? I'd be curious so I learn for next time! Thank you!

Comment: I am using `[\w-]+` to match a username which means 1+ word characters or hyphen.